# Why set an "Accept" in Spring Resttemplate is invalid

Tags: spring, resttemplate

Here is my code:

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(src, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        System.out.println(responseEntity);
```

why my log file print accept is : text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*

Comment: 22:47:05.959 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]

Comment: You can edit your post after posting it (links below the tags). (In fact, "anyone" can.)